# AWS Windows EC2 instance does not recognize assigned IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-s3

Initially I launched a brand-new Windows Server 2016 server EC2. I assigned a **S3 full admin** IAM role to this instance when launching it. I installed CLI on it. I started a CMD window, and typed in "**aws s3 ls**". It lists all my buckets. All working fine.

I then created an AMI from this instance. I launched a new instance from this instance with that **S3 full admin** IAM role. "**aws s3 ls**" still works.

Then, after a number of days, when I repeat the above process (launching an instance from the same AMI), "**aws s3 ls**" will stop working, with the following error:

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

It happened many times. Every time I rebuilt a new Windows Server, install CLI, assign the S3 full admin role to the instance, it works. After a number of days, when I launch a new instance from the exact same AMI, "**aws s3 ls**" will stop working.

It is so mysterious! Can someone shed some light on this please?

Comment: For each new EC2 instance you launch, you must assign the role it. The role does not get bundled in the AMI.

Answer (score 2):

The IAM role does not get bundled with your AMI.

So when you launch your new EC2 instances from your AMI, you must assign the IAM role to the new EC2 instances that are launched. Without the role assigned at launch or afterwards, the CLI cannot find the credentials.

Comment: Another way to say this might be "IAM Roles are associated with instances rather than AMI machine templates". Just in case it's not clear to everyone.

Comment: I understand that the IAM role is not bundled with the AMI. Everytime I launch a new instance from this AMI, I assign the same role to the new instance, but it will stop working one day.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently with a Windows EC2 instance deployed from my own AMI.
As @Kugel (https://serverfault.com/users/138998/kugel) has mentioned in their answer (Previous answer of this), one can see that the NextHop values when is executed the Get-NetRoute command doesn't changes in the new instance, and the instance remains the previous values for the existent network configurations in the base instance from where the AMI was generated.

Then, to resolve this issue, I have created new Net Routes with the new NextHop values and deleted the oldest ones. Taking as example the output given by @kugel, the creation of the new routes will be:

```
Set-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex 3 -DestinationPrefix "169.254.169.254/32" -RouteMetric 15 -NextHop 10.2.6.1
```

Repeat the previous command for the rest of the Destinations prefixes (169.254.169.123/32, 169.254.169.249/32, 169.254.169.250/32, 169.254.169.251/32 and 169.254.169.253/32)

Once the new net routes has been created, you can delete the oldest with the command:

```
Remove-NetRoute -NextHop 10.2.4.1
```

The previous command will delete all occurrences that has as NextHop that IP.

References for commands:

- Set new route:
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-netroute?view=win10-ps
- Delete routes:
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/remove-netroute?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 1):

I found this question while having the same issue.  What ended up solving it for me is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45116140/768403) which I have quoted below so as to not have an answer with just a link.

> There is a script call InitializeInstance.ps1 that resets some configuration information.
>
> For example, if the instance has changed subnets it might not work correctly due to cached routing rules. The InitializeInstance.ps1 can correct this.

As the top comment on that answer points out:

> In Windows Instance, this script is located here: C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\InitializeInstance.ps1

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me all the time with new Windows 2019 instances. I create an instance configure it, snapshot it and then when I launch the AMI in a different subnet or AZ the IAM roles are broken.

What I found it is that the routing is gets horribly broken. You see, AWS uses magic IPs set up on the machine to retrieve various things, including IAM credentials.

When you snapshot a machine the Windows Route table gets snapshontted with it and when you launch an AMI the Routing table is not modified and ends up pointing to the wrong gateway.

Here's my example:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-NetRoute

ifIndex DestinationPrefix                              NextHop                                  RouteMetric ifMetric PolicyStore
------- -----------------                              -------                                  ----------- -------- -----------
3       255.255.255.255/32                             0.0.0.0                                          256 15       ActiveStore
1       255.255.255.255/32                             0.0.0.0                                          256 75       ActiveStore
3       224.0.0.0/4                                    0.0.0.0                                          256 15       ActiveStore
1       224.0.0.0/4                                    0.0.0.0                                          256 75       ActiveStore
3       169.254.169.254/32                             10.2.4.1                                          15 15       ActiveStore
3       169.254.169.253/32                             10.2.4.1                                          15 15       ActiveStore
3       169.254.169.251/32                             10.2.4.1                                          15 15       ActiveStore
3       169.254.169.250/32                             10.2.4.1                                          15 15       ActiveStore
3       169.254.169.249/32                             10.2.4.1                                          15 15       ActiveStore
3       169.254.169.123/32                             10.2.4.1                                          15 15       ActiveStore
1       127.255.255.255/32                             0.0.0.0                                          256 75       ActiveStore
1       127.0.0.1/32                                   0.0.0.0                                          256 75       ActiveStore
1       127.0.0.0/8                                    0.0.0.0                                          256 75       ActiveStore
3       10.2.6.255/32                                  0.0.0.0                                          256 15       ActiveStore
3       10.2.6.138/32                                  0.0.0.0                                          256 15       ActiveStore
3       10.2.6.0/24                                    0.0.0.0                                          256 15       ActiveStore
3       0.0.0.0/0                                      10.2.6.1                                           0 15       ActiveStore
3       ff00::/8                                       ::                                               256 15       ActiveStore
1       ff00::/8                                       ::                                               256 75       ActiveStore
3       fe80::b8bf:5c16:bc0d:562f/128                  ::                                               256 15       ActiveStore
3       fe80::/64                                      ::                                               256 15       ActiveStore
1       ::1/128                                        ::                                               256 75       ActiveStore
```

Please note how default gateway is `10.2.6.1` and is correct for this subnet.
However all the magic routes still point to previous gateway `10.2.4.1` from the old AZ.

To fix this you have to manually fix the routes. If you have this in an Auto-Scaling group you might have to write a powershell that runs after boot to fix routes.

Answer (score 0):

This is very old but there was pretty much zero help for a similar issue that's current (Q1 2024).  On even the latest instance metadata versions (IMDSv2) you may find yourself in a situation where the `iam` endpoint simply doesn't exist, but the other metadata does:

```
$token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Headers @{ "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token-ttl-seconds" = 21600 } -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token

# You should see your role name here
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{ "X-aws-ec2-metadata-token" = $token } -Uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
```

In my case `/meta-data/iam/*` was missing, as was the `iam` key itself.

The cause was adding and linking my instance role after the instance had already had its first boot.  Turns out there are some initialization scripts that run on first boot, and if your instance profile and role aren't linked to your machine at that time, you are out of luck.  I had a new enough instance I didn't dig in to how to re-run these scripts, I'm sure it's possible.  When I terminated my instance and started a new one, the `iam` key was suddenly there and the aws cli and powershell tools were happy.